# Best practice of database design in django project?

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a project where users has multiple permissions based on role assigned.

The superadmin will create new role and can decide which menus is allowed(with specific permissions inside menu) for the role dynamically.

Admin can assign rights(for e.g. can_view, can_approve) in some menu to some role and so on.

In this way there can be so many bool flags and some of the flags will be unnecessary for some menu.

If I go in like Django Group and permissions model base then there can be so many permissions.
For example : ( can create menua , can update menub...)

OR any other way which will be appropriate ?

```
class User():
   id
   name
   role_id(fk)

class DashboardMenu():
   id
   name
   codename(unique)
   parent_id

class Role():
   id
   name(unique)
   desc
   menus(menu_ids (many to many))
   

class RoleMenuRight():
   id
   role_id(fk)
   menu_id(fk)
   can_create
   can_delete
   can_update
   can_view
   can_approve
   can_reject
   #other bool flags
```

Another approach

```
class User():
   id
   name
   role_id(fk)

class Permission():
   id
   name
   codename(unique)
  

class Role():
   id
   name(unique)
   desc
   permissions(permission_ids (many to many))
```

second approach is easy but with this approach I think I cannot fulfill below requirement.

I want to make api which will list only the authorized menus of user with their permissions in this menu.

for example:

```
[
{"id":1,
 "menu_name":"name",
 "user_can_create":true,
 "user_can_update":false
  .....
},
 {"id":2,
 "menu_name":"name",
 "user_can_create":true,
 "user_can_update":false
  .....
}
```

]

also for the post request api the payload will be:

```
    {"role_id":1,
    "menus":[  {"menu_id":1,"can_create":true,"can_update":true,"can_view":true,"can_delete":false},
         {"menu_id":2,"can_create":false,"can_update":true,"can_view":true,"can_delete":false},
         {"menu_id":3,"can_create":true,"can_update":false,"can_view":true,"can_delete":false}]}
```

For this type of requirement I want to design my models. Will approach1 fulfill the requirement?

Comment: the second seems good and simple but can you clarify what exactly the form you need in api response

Comment: @MohamedBeltagy question updated.

Answer (score 2):

After 1 hour struggle, I got this. I hope this help you.

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   role = models.ForeignKey("Role", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    
class Role(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   desc = models.TextField()
   menus = models.ManyToManyField("DashboardMenu", thorough="RoleMenuMapping")
  
class RoleMenuMapping(models.Model):
  role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
  dash_board_menu = models.ForeignKey("DashboardMenu", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
  #below fk make each menu related with role has one permission, 
  #if you relate permission m2m with role or menus, you will confuse when get privileges. 
  #Because, they will be multiple when you get.
  privilege = models.ForeignKey("Privilege", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class Privilege(models.Model):
   can_create = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   can_delete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   can_update = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   can_view = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   can_approve = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   #other bool flags
    
 class DashboardMenu(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   codename = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
   parent = models.ForeignKey(self, null=True, blank=True)

  [
{"id":1,
 "menu_name":"name",
 "user_can_create":true,
 "user_can_update":false
  .....
},
 {"id":2,
 "menu_name":"name",
 "user_can_create":true,
 "user_can_update":false
  .....
}

can get by 
    
user = User.objects.filter(id==100).prefetch_related('role__rolemenumapping_set__privilege','role__rolemenumapping_set__menu')
   
   return [ {
      "id":row.menu.id,
      "name":row.menu.name,
      ....
      "user_can_create": row.privilege.can_create,
      "user_can_update":row.privilege.can_create,
      
     } for row in user.role.rolemenumapping_set
  ]
  
 
  {"role_id":1,
    "menus":[  
{"menu_id":1,"can_create":true,"can_update":true,"can_view":true,"can_delete":false},
         {"menu_id":2,"can_create":false,"can_update":true,"can_view":true,"can_delete":false},
         {"menu_id":3,"can_create":true,"can_update":false,"can_view":true,"can_delete":false}]}
    
This request can be done by below:

role= Role.objects.get(pk=role_id)

for menu in menus:
    menu_id = menu.pop("menu_id")
    #below should return single privilege row!
    privilege = Privilege.objects.filter(**menu)
    role_menu_map = RoleMenuMapping.objects(role=role,menu_id=menu_id)
    role_menu_map.privilege = privilege
    role_menu_map.save()

# I know upper code hit db a lot. 
# This code comes from your request. 
# If this kind of request is frequent, you'd better change each permissions to one privilege_id.
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do you think my approach1 will also work ?

Comment: @D_P 1st answer work, but wasting space on DB, if service go further. Same permission rows are duplicated too many. If there is N roles, there is also N roles * 6 permission Boolean on Role (most of them using most common permission). But, if you separate permission from Role, only N permission ids on Role.
And more, If you add only 1 permission using your way, you need alter N rows to just add 1 column. But other way need only alter 2 to the 6th power of Permission rows.
Does it make sense? If not, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. +1 . I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: You have to break outside the mindset of just literally translating a SQL database in django and take the leap into letting django handle the lower level. You should never have a "pure" join table in Django or you're doing something wrong. You CAN do it like this in Django but it'll get much more confusing and error-prone, especially when you're CRUDing in views. This is a good start but the RoleMenuMapping table should be something you let Django do.

Comment: @Tyk 

1. RoleMenuMapping is not pure join table. It has extra field, privilege(foreignkey). This manner is documneted officially. [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) 
2. Declaring MappingTable give user more control for table. This can allow user queryset like `RoleMenuMapping.objects.filter(role_id=100)`. Also, If you declair mapping table, there is relation on DB schema view explicitly with DB tools like workbench.

Comment: Sure you could do that, by why not just use OneToOne, ForeignKey and ManyToMany to handle all that if you're using django?

Comment: @Tyk I just typed pseudocode, as D_P had written.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something like in django contrib auth [django.contrib.auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/) You can create permissions like you have, and instead of using role - create group with permissions for types of users.

Comment: I think my requirements are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the best database design for django-rest-framework is just the database design best practices using django ORM. And django ORM is based on SQL & relational DB best practices in mind.

To help you with your query of database best practice with django ORM for REST API, I would suggest follow this page & packages if you are thinking about usinf DRF [https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#:~:text=The%20DRY%20Rest%20Permissions%20package%20provides%20the%20ability,to%20a%20client%20app%20through%20the%20API%27s%20serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#:%7E:text=The%20DRY%20Rest%20Permissions%20package%20provides%20the%20ability,to%20a%20client%20app%20through%20the%20API%27s%20serializer).

you can also choose any role based permission type 3rd party packages from django eco system to customize them as your need. but you should first increase your understanding of django ORM models & contrib.auth permissions basic to extend it further for your need or to understand other 3rd party implementation. this is my general guideline for new django ORM developers.

This article is very old but help you understand how django ORM works much better https://schinckel.net/2014/08/26/avoiding-sql-antipatterns-using-django-(and-postgres)/ .

Also you can try https://django-role-permissions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html which support role & objec based permissions.

Comment: I've used django.contrib.auth permissions but for this scenario i don't think it will fit. If it can fit then I am happy to implement.

Comment: I suggested checking django role based permission packages as you are trying to reinvent the wheel which is WET.

Comment: Do you know any third party packages you may suggest?

Comment: edited the answer with that

Comment: Thanks I just quick checked the package. My requirement is superadmin should have the every  decision for e.g. CRUD role dynamically and crud menu permissions inside role dynamically. Do you think it can be done with this package?

Comment: ofcourse that should be possible. as it just extended the core contrib.auth logics.

Comment: This way, api with permissions can not deliver information to frontend what can be pushed by user and what should be blocked by frontend in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The second way is more correct.

The great thing about Django models is that it handles many-to-many tables and other SQL stuff under the hood. The bad thing is that Django documentation is IMO really hard to use if you don't already have a really good idea what you're looking for.

So the second way is the way I'd go. Here's my implementation. You'll notice that you don't actually need to define the one or one side of the many in the one-to-many or many-to-many. Here's how I understand to implement the second with what I understand best practices to be*.

I'm not actually running/testing any of this code so treat it like pseudo code.

```
from django.db import models
class User(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Why didn't I mention id (aka primary key, or "pk"), or didn't mention role_id? Because we don't need to talk about role_id here and can let django magic handle pk. You're probably doing something very out there or wrong otherwise with pk.

You won't actually even need the "role_id" in Django! That's abstracted. If you're confused, keep going because that's where related_name comes in via the ForeignKey and ManyToMany fields.

If I understand correctly a user should have one or more roles but potentially many permissions via each role. So we make role next.

```
class Role():
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
  desc = models.CharField(max_length=1023)
  user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='roles')
```

Now we can access a users role(s) via user.roles. Django just magically added a "roles" field into users via the related_name. So now more magic happens here- we create a many Permissions to many Role here:

```
class Permission(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField("Role",related_name="permissions")
```

Not sure if you actually need codename, but hey.

Now look at role. You're creating a many permissions to many roles here. Now you can access permissions associated with a role via role.permissions or rolls associated with a permission via permission.roles. Related name is what allows that attribute to be called "permissions" or "roles"

Bonus reading:

*Except I use "related_name" for ease of use and readability instead of the default weird way. The risk of related_name is that they must be unique or bad things can happen. There's a default name you can accomplish the same result with since related name is optional but I've never used it.

The string with the name of the class as the first arg in ManyToMany and ForeignKey must be the name of the class on the other side of the relationship. Those are not arbitrary. The related names can be arbitrary, by convention I believe they should be plural.

So yeah the second way was more right- you don't need "utility tables" or whatever the proper name for join tables is in SQL in Django- that's done under the hood by Django.

It also sounds like what you want to is already done in the django auth library which I'm not yet familiar with, though hopefully this at least answers your question and explains how you can implement that yourself or modify it if you need to. I've never modified those default models directly, but you can easily tie in via a field like so:

Imports:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

Now inside the class

```
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='this_associated_with_built_in_users')
```

The thing with django is that all the pieces of what you need to know are there, but are spread out in the documentation.

Useful references:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#relationships

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Related name explained here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Also if you want to know how to do this with without related name, I believe this is how to do. I never have:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-related-name

Comment: Your answer does not have `class DashBoardMenu`. Where do they be placed following @D_P  request?

Comment: You said, "Not sure if you actually need codename, but hey.", but D_P's work make sense. The name is for frontend(changeable at anytime), and the codename for backend use like name=master, codename=TIER_0. It is more clear than using pk for writing code.

Comment: There are likely much better ways to do so. If you have a choices kwarg in the model like here you can set a human-readable name, or create one in the view generated off rather than store a whole new column. Using something besides the primary key to get() a specific object seems like a bad idea imo. 

@rumbarum I don't see why we need one?

Comment: According to your models here,  User will have multiple roles(which I don't want) and Role will have only one `User` (I think no one want this).  And also in the permission model I didn't liked the idea of having manytomany with Roles, but instead it should be opposite. @Tyk

Comment: You can just change the ForeignKey to a OneToOne as so:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Alternatively you can just put the foreignkey in user instead if you want to reverse the one to many.

As far as the "opposite" of a manytomany is a manytomany, so I'm not sure what you mean there.

Comment: @Tyk opposite means it would be better if we put `permissions` inside `Role` instead of `Role` having in  `permission` model. Like the django auth `Group` model has `permissions` inside Group.

Comment: Then you simply put:

permissions = models.ManyToManyField("Permission",related_name="roles")

under roles.

Either way function exactly the same as far as accessing them via related name. There is no difference.

Comment: @Tyk I think It's up to operation policy. If choices are in the model, when display name change, Django should be deployed. If display name is on the DB, only single query required without deploy.

Comment: @Tyk I mean codename for comparison, `request.user.permission.codename == TIER_0` is more clear than `request.user.permission_id == 1`

Comment: Ah I can see why that would make sense and be worth another column in some cases.